# Substitute for jaggery in chutney

Tags: substitutions, sugar, chutney

I'm making an Indian tomato and ginger chutney. What can I find in Brisbane to use as a substitute for 200 grams of jaggery?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you meant "Jaggery" (aka Panela) a unrefined cane sugar product.  If so, I would suggest a "Muscovado" sugar, as it is whole or partially unrefinued cane sugar.  You may need to experiment and blend between dark and medium muscovado to get the taste you desire.  I suggest either try a medium brown muscovado or a 1:1 ratio of dark and medium brown muscovado sugar.

Comment: Also palm sugar or dark coconut sugar can be used, with a similar taste. Though these may be as hard to find as jaggery